# Perform queries which return a value for success of failure

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

How can I know if a query like this succeeded or failed? E.g. if the node with this id doesn't exist I would expect an error.

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(u:User)")
    .Where("u.id = '" + userId+ "'")
    .DetachDelete("u")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Based on the result I want to return the correct HTTP-Statuscode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using optional match  (and perhaps parameters as well, since they perform better?)

To make this work fast, make sure you have an index (probably even a constraint) set on the id property.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User {id:$userId})
RETURN u,  NOT u IS NULL AS found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an "error", this query uses the APOC procedure [apoc.util.validate](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/overview/apoc.util/apoc.util.validate/) to assert that `u` is found:

```
client.Cypher
    .OptionalMatch("(u:User)")
    .Where("u.id = $userId")
    .WithParam("userId", userId)
    .Call("apoc.util.validate(u IS NULL, 'User not found. id=%s', [$userId])")
    .DetachDelete("u")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

An exception with a message like the following will be generated if `u` is not found:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.util.validate`: Caused by:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: User not found. id=abc

This query passes the `userId` as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), which is more secure and efficient.

[UPDATE]

If you just want a lightweight way to get a boolean result, something like this may work:

```
bool userDeleted = (await client.Cypher
    .OptionalMatch("(u:User)")
    .Where("u.id = $userId")
    .WithParam("userId", 2)
    .DetachDelete("u")  
    .Return(u => Return.As<bool>("NOT (u IS NULL)"))
    .ResultsAsync)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: This sounds like it is unusual to get an error? How would I inform my frontend otherwise, that the deletion of an element did not work? Without an error I could run into an unsynced state on the frontend.

Comment: See my UPDATE. Not tested.

Comment: If Neo4j broke - you would get an exception being thrown, in any other scenario - if you got a 'false' back from Cybersam's query - all the means is that the node wasn't there (which isn't an error) - and your UI was out of sync already. There's no way you could get an error that I can think of - that you wouldn't get an exception.